# How to validate file using hook_file_validate?

Tags: hooks, files

I want to validate my file, I'm using

> hook_file_validate

```
function test_file_validate($file) {
  $errors = array();

  if (empty($file->filename)) {
    $errors[] = t("The file's name is empty. Please give a name to the file.");
  }
  if (retstrlen($file->filename) > 255) {
    $errors[] = t("The file's name exceeds the 255 characters limit. Please rename the file and try again.");
  }
  return $errors;
}
```

But, when I am going to `print_r($file)` I am not getting any values, please let know how to use this function

Comment: does this hook exist? I've never heard about. And couldn't find any information..

Comment: oops, my bad, it does exist.. Did you flush the cache?

Comment: What it the file peramater? Is it a form tag which is posted by form. Or it is a $file which you have assigned some file path properly?

Comment: hook_file_validate exists, Folks please see the link on D.o https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_validate/7

Comment: Sidenote: don't use `print_r()`. Instead, install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use `dpm()` function - it will display an element tree of your object/array which is very easy to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 just use **drupal_set_message**

```
/**
 * Implementing hook_file_validate
 * @param type $file : Object
 * @return type : array of error messages
 */
function hook_file_validate($file) {
    drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($file, 1) . "</pre>");
    $errors = array();
    if ($file->source == 'field_article_file_und_0') {
        if ($file->filesize > 290081) {
            $errors[] = t("The file's exceeds upload limit. Please try again.");
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_file_validate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_validate/7) is called by [`file_validate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_validate/7).  It lets you supply custom validation to supplement the validators that already exists.  You need to give it valid file object to work with.  Here is an example of how to use. In this example, it *always* produces an error message (so you don't have to type in absurdly long filenames, etc. to test).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_validate().
 */
function MYMODULE_file_validate($file) {
  debug('hook_file_validate was called');
  // Add your custom validation code here. E.g.:
 $errors = array();
 if (!mb_detect_encoding($file->filename, 'ASCII', true)) {
   $errors[] = t("Please don't use non-ASCII charcters in filenames.");
  }
  $errors[] = t("This error is always added, just to test that it works.");
}
```

Now, most of the stand upload functions that comes with Drupal already calls `file_validate`, so you should see any errors generated by it.

However, if you're creating a custom upload method, you need to call `file_validate` somewhere in your code, for instance in your form validation code:

```
// Load the file object:
$fid = $form_state['values']['image'];
$file = file_load($fid);
// Use one of the existing validator callbacks to check if it is an image.
$validators = array(
  ' file_validate_is_image' => array(),
);

// When this function is called, hook_file_validate is also called.
$errors = file_validate($file, $validators);
foreach ($errors as $key => $error) {
  drupal_set_message($error);
}
```

Note that instead of using `hook_file_validate()`, you can write your own validation callbacks and add those to the `$validators` array.  I prefer to use this method instead of `hook_file_validate`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Sachin I think the problem is that you are not watching output at right place.
If you are uploading a file at a node's edit then you will see your message there only.
For example I tried it for you by uploading a file with file name larger than 25 characters then at time of uploading I found the this message:

[image]

I have also used this print_r($file) in my code and found details about file being uploading in Ajax pop up.
And my code as as follows :

```
 function common_file_validate($file) {  print_r($file);exit;
  $errors = array();

  if (empty($file->filename)) {
    $errors[] = t("The file's name is empty. Please give a name to the file.");
  }
  if (strlen($file->filename) > 25) {
    $errors[] = t("The file's name exceeds the 25 characters limit. Please rename the file and try again.");
  }

  return $errors;
}
```

[image]